# Does telethon telegram client has any command handler?

Tags: command, bots, telegram, telethon

Does the telethon library supports any command handler such that I can build a telegram bot, and when someone types, lets say "/add 123" (both handling command and taking in argument), it would reply by 123?

I know there're many other libraries that are able to do it, for example pyrogram, telegram.ext. However, I'm already using a very specific functions within telethon, so I would like to add these new features to my bot with only telethon